# Android 12 - CAMERA2 - Pictures are corrupted when saving

Tags: android, photo, android-camera2, data-corruption

I found an anomaly during tests with this particular device, the details are below:

**Hardware:** samsung,SM-A326B (Smartphone Samsung A32)

**OS:** Android 12

**ONE UI:** 4.1

**Google Play:** 01/may/22

**Patch level:** 01/june/22

These are the specs of one device that works properly, the only differences that I see are related to different version of the patch level.

**Hardware:** samsung,SM-A515F (Smartphone Samsung A51)

**OS:** Android 12

**ONE UI:** 4.1

**Google Play:** 01/may/22

**Patch level:** 01/may/22

I have implemented a customization of camera2 in my application, this always works except with this device, the specific anomaly is that the images are saved completely white and are corrupted, the image can only be recovered by third party software.

These are the permissions I ask for in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps " />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

This is the code that I use to save the images

```
public void saveCameraImage(Image mImage, File mFile, String mOrientation, Context context) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        wil.WriteFile("saveImage - Exception: " + e.getMessage(), context);
    } finally {
        mImage.close();
        if (null != fileOutputStream) {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                wil.WriteFile("saveImage - Exception: " + e.getMessage(), context);
            } finally {
                saveExifData(mFile.getPath(), context);
                createThumbs(mOrientation, mFile, context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function that I named "saveExifData"

```
private void saveExifData(String filepath, Context context) {
        try {
            if (filepath.endsWith(IMAGE_FORMAT)) {
                File file = new File(filepath);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    DbGest dbGest = DbGest.getInstance(context);
                    String dateTime = dbGest.getTimestampFromFileToSend(filepath, "dateTime", context);
                    String dateTimeGps = dbGest.getTimestampFromFileToSend(filepath, "gps", context);
                    String dateTimeDesc = dbGest.getTimestampFromFileToSend(filepath, "dateTimeDesc", context);
    
                    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filepath);
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COPYRIGHT, "xxxxx ");
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, Build.MANUFACTURER + "," + Build.MODEL);
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SOFTWARE, dbGest.getSetting("appName", context));
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, dateTime);
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL, dateTime);
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT, "Immagine scattata tramite " + dbGest.getSetting("appName", context) + " il " + dateTimeDesc);
    
                    CoordinatesData position = DbGest.getInstance(context).getBetterPositionKnown(context);
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, String.valueOf(position.getLat()));
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(position.getLng()));
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP, dateTimeGps);
                    exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_SPEED, String.valueOf(position.getSpeed()));
                    exifInterface.setLatLong(position.getLat(), position.getLng());
                    exifInterface.saveAttributes();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            wil.WriteFile("saveExifData - Exception: " + e.getMessage(), context);
        }
    }
```

So I guess it's not a permission issue, also there are no exceptions, so I don't know how to fix this

Comment: I have found several models of samsung devices cause corruption in saved file if you apply location exif data. We use camerax though which should be using camera2 under the hood. The only exif we set is the location via the OutputFileOptions metadata. Without this field the files are fine.

Answer (score 0):

After several test and debugging I find the cause of the bug.

The problem it is in the "saveExifData", for some reason this row of code

```
exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_COPYRIGHT, "xxxx");
```

it is the cause of the problem

Comment: If you are definitely sure it is caused by the ExifInterface, then I would recommend you to immediately open a ticket in the Google IssueTracker as this would be a major bug. Also, are you using the framework ExifInterface, or the support library ExifInterface? It is recommended to use the support library one instead of the framework. In either case you should still open a bug in the IssueTracker.

Comment: Hi, I imported this library

import androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface;

Comment: Then, open a bug in the issue tracker. When creating it, make sure to select the support library exif interface as the component (Android Public Tracker > App Development > Jetpack (androidx) > Exifinterface): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q